# Plot first N number of data from txt file Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a txt file with two columns having 4000 data. **Now I want to plot only the first 1000 data from each column**. I have used the following code(below) to plot all data. Looking help me to plot the first N(1000) number of data extracting from txt file.

```
    x = data[:,0]
    y = data[:,1]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

This is the part of my txt file:

[image: This is the part of my txt file]

Comment: Hint: What do you think the `:` does in `data[:,0]`?

Comment: To read first column of txt file

Comment: @PrakashGyawali try this one. i think u will love iloc. x.iloc[1:3, 0:2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slices:

```
x = data[:1000,0]
```

represents the first 1000 entries of the first column.
In general:

```
my_list[a:b]
```

contains the data from index a to index b-1.

Comment: Checkout the following link for Array Slicing: https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy_array_slicing.asp